# difference between dropdownlist and usercontrol with a dropdownlist

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu, user-controls

i like to get initial value to my DDL and write ddl1.Text="6" - it works fine..
i try to do the same to a DDL which is part of a simple usercontrol(3 DDLs which create a date) - this doesn't work!!!

---

in default.aspx i tried-

```
DateUserControl2.SetD("17");
DateUserControl2.SetM("7");
((DropDownList)DateUserControl2.Controls[4]).Text = "2003";
```

---

in DateUserControl.ascx.cs
i put all the listitems created in Page_Init and it works fine

the other methods

---

```
public void SetD(object d)
{
   this.DropDownListDuc.Text = d + "";
}
public void SetM(object m)
{
    this.DropDownListMuc.SelectedValue = m + "";   
}
```

when i try to trace, i see that the methods are ok, but, for example,if d parameter is 4 and
`this.DropDownListDuc.Text = 4 + "";`
is performed, still NOTHING changes!!!
(again, the same line in a "simple" DDL,like    `DropDownList1.Text = "20";`  changes the DDL to 20!!
changing a Label in the eser control works too. it is just a DDL_in_a_usercontrol problem
thanks!

Comment: Whenever you see yourself with DateUserControl2 and other default name number in your code. You need to stop and name properly. You will love yourself for it in the future and avoid benevolent people not caring about your problems because if you didn't care to think of what something is, why should they ;)

Answer (score 0):

Well, keep in mind that you are NOT allowed to have two controls with the same "id" on one page.

But, what then occurs if you drop the user control two times on the same web page?

I have a hotel edit UC.

So, I can do this:

Say this markup:

```
        <uc1:UHotelEdit runat="server" ID="UHotelEdit"
            MyTable ="tblHotelsA" />

        <div style="clear:both;height:30px">
        </div>

        <uc1:UHotelEdit runat="server" ID="UHotelEdit2"
            MyTable ="tblHotelsA" />
```

So, note we have TWO UC's on the page. UhotelEdit, and UhotelEdit2.

My page load code is this:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            UHotelEdit.MyPk = 6;
            UHotelEdit.LoadData();

            UHotelEdit2.MyPk = 7;
            UHotelEdit2.LoadData();
        }
    }
```

And now we have this:

[image]

So, in above, we have Hotel Name text box, first name, last name etc.

But, we are NOT allowed to have multiple "id" of the same control on the page.

So, how can/could I set the hotel name of the first control to Zoo, and Zoo2 for the 2nd one?

Well, all of the controls are "nested" inside of the UC.

This is quite much like a grid view, or whatever. So, you have two choices:

if several of the controls had to be "often" changed, then make a public property in the UC.

or, you can get/grab/pluck out the control name of the UC.

eg this:

```
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox txtHotel = UHotelEdit.FindControl("txtHotel") as TextBox;
        TextBox txtHotel2 = UHotelEdit2.FindControl("txtHotel") as TextBox;

        txtHotel.Text = "Zoo";
        txtHotel2.Text = "Zoo2";
    }
```

And thus we now have this:

[image]

But, if you had to "often" change the hotel name text box above?

Well, then add a public property to the UC, say like this:

```
    public string HotelName
    {
        get { return txtHotel.Text; }
        set { txtHotel.Text = value; }
    }
```

And now our code becomes this:

```
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        UHotelEdit.HotelName = "Zoo";
        UHotelEdit2.HotelName = "Zoo2";

    }
```

So, for common or often controls to be changed? Setup a get/set for that control. For the rare and not common used?

Then you can use find control. Quite much you do the same to get a control out of  repeater, listview, gridview etc. - you in general have to use find control for those nested controls.

Well, everything quite much works the same, but we have to prefix the control(s) with the name of the user control (id) we used when dropping on the page.

but, if you have JavaScript code, then how can I select the first one (hotel name) vs the 2nd one?

Turns out, all controls rendering inside of a UC will PREFIX the control with the name of the user control!!!

So, on the page you find two hotel text boxes,

UHotelEdit_txtHotel

UhotelEdit2_txtHotel

But, they are not exposed that way to code behind (just like controls nested in a listview or repeater also are not). but, they exist and jQuery selectors can be used against those controls.

In code behind, you have to use UC.findcontrol("txtHotel") to pluck out a reference to that control in the UC - since its nested inside.

So, if your UC has a dropdown list, and you want to with ease to change that value? Then add a PUBLIC method to the control that allows you do to this. So, while the controls inside are not exposed, you can with ease add a simple public method that allows you to change the drop down list value.